# How to install midori?

Tags: software-installation, midori

I see lots of posts on the internet on how to use or optimize Midori but everyone seems to assume that the Pi 2 B comes with Midori. I don't know about anyone else, but mine came with Epiphany. How the heck do I install Midori?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: It came with Noobs, installed Wheezy. nsilent22's answer worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are running raspbian: `sudo apt-get install midori`

Comment: now that I see that, it makes sense. Thank you. And yes, it works.